# pyspark udf: how do i register known type?

Tags: types, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a spark dataframe column that contains a complicated data structure (essentially a hierarchical mix of arrays and structs).
I now want to build an udf mapper function, that takes one instance row by row and returns one instance of the same type structure.
I will have to register the udf's type whatsoever. Is there any way to reference to the already known columns's type structure or to tell the function, it returns its input type? 
Thx for your help.

I want use my udf like this. The modified column is supposed to contain items of the same type

```
mydata.select(col("items"), myudf("items"))
```

In order to do that, I create a python function, that pythonically doesn't care about types. But nonetheless it is required to register it with some type.

```
def f(item):
    return newitem

myudf = pyspark.sql.functions.udf(f, item.type)
```

The type actually is a complicated array structure, which is not to be handled manually. I'm looking for a fast way to obtain the type, write it in a variable and use it as argument in the udf-registration.

Comment: Could you please add some code in order for us to give a more specific answer?

Comment: ok, done. hope, it is a little bit clearer right now.